# Is there a way to make a child div override parent style and like a portal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a parent div that contains a child div. The parent style is

```
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  z-index: 8888;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
```

and the child style is

```
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
```

is there a way to make the child act like a portal where the region it's in it removed the parent div blur and background color?

tl;dr
something that looks like this

[image: example result without backdrop filter]

Comment: How about this in your child's style: `backdrop-filter: none;` or `backdrop-filter: initial;` to remove that filter? [MDN docs: backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

Comment: Didn't work, the background is still blurred and dark, I need the child to basically clip the parent where it removes the filter and background color based on it's own width and height

Comment: I'm pretty sure your best bet would be to place your "child" element elsewhere in the DOM tree so it's not affected by the "parent" filter, then position it atop the "parent" with a higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

-- edit --

If the question is how to revert the backdrop filter in the sub div, you can use

```
backdrop-filter: none;
```

BUT, if you want to inherit this from the parent of the parent, you need to do this in JavaScript

```
element.style.backdropFilter = element.parentNode.parentNode.style.backdropFilter;
```

---

Three ways to do this in CSS

1 use relative div positions

```
div : {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  background-clip: text;
  z-index: 8888;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div div {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
}
```

2 Use IDs

```
#mainID : {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  background-clip: text;
  z-index: 8888;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#subDivID {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
}
```

3 Use classes

```
.mainID : {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  background-clip: text;
  z-index: 8888;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.subDivClass {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 400px;
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to revert the backdrop-filter for the second div.

Comment: exactly as the code provided doesn't differ from what is originally posted

Comment: @YaDev I have edited the code to include how to revert the backdrop-filter